# I have a Schengen visa from Netherlands Embassy but I want to spent two days in Paris first before I go to the Netherlands is it allow

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands

I have a Schengen visa from the Netherlands Embassy, but I want to visit Paris first before I move to the Netherlands; Is it allowed?

Comment: What type of visa is it? Generally, it's not a problem. The Schengen Visa gives you access to the entire Schengen Area unless the visa is restricted to a particular country (which is extremely rare).

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Schengen visa for all "Schengen states" (or the translation of that term) you can *in principle* visit any Schengen country. You submitted an itinerary when you applied for the visa.

- If it looks as if you lied to get the visa, your entry may be refused.
- If it looks as if you are making a minor adjustment to your trip, there is no problem.

So if you are still going to the Netherlands, and if you spend more time there than in France, and if you have the documents for onward travel when you land in France, there will be no problem.